# error: non-floating-point argument in call to function ‘__builtin_isnan’

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <math.h>       

int main()

{

    //  printf ("isnan(0.0)       : %d\n",isnan(0.0));

    //  printf ("isnan(1.0/0.0)   : %d\n",isnan(1.0/0.0));

    //  printf ("isnan(-1.0/0.0)  : %d\n",isnan(-1.0/0.0));

    //  printf ("isnan(sqrt(-1.0)): %d\n",isnan(sqrt(sqrt(-1.0))));

    //  printf ("isnan(sqrt(-1.0)): %d\n",isnan(sqrt(floor(-1.0))));

    //  printf ("isnan(-1.0/0.0)): %d\n",isnan(-1.0/0.0));

    //  printf ("isnan(sqrt(-1.0)): %d\n",isnan(sqrt(floor(sqrt(-1.0)))));

    printf ("isnan(1/0): %d\n",isnan(1/0));

    //  printf ("isnan(sqrt(-1.0)): %d\n",isnan(sqrt(-1/0)));

    return 0;
}
```

I got this error:

i

```
snann.c:23:28: error: non-floating-point argument in call to function ‘__builtin_isnan’
 printf ("isnan(1/0): %d\n",isnan(1/0));
```

What is the problem?

isnan works fine with other inputs (the ones that I commented).

I need to solve this problem because when I compile GNSS-R software, I faced with this error too.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Well 1 and 0 _are_ integers, which are _non-floating point_? So what do you expect to happen? Use ˋ1.0/0ˋ and it should work.

Comment: There is right and there is wrong way to learn C++. Learning by guessing is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you provided a non-floating-point argument to `isnan`, as it says.

When we flip over to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan), we see:

> Determines [whether] the given **floating point number** arg is a not-a-number (NaN) value. The macro returns an integral value.

`1` is an integer, and `0` is an integer, so `1/0` is an integer.

So, you're using the macro wrong and, if GNSS-R does `isnan(1/0)`, then GNSS-R is wrong too.

Actually your whole program's behaviour is undefined due to the integer division by zero, but that's another issue!

Comment: Thanks for response. So you mean It is a bug for GNSS-R software. And there is no way to compile it?! However, when I call g++ instead gcc I can compile the above simple code and recieve neither 0 nor 1 but it says core dump!

Answer (score 0):

`std::isnan` should accept one of the decimal types(`float`, `double`). `1/0` it's not decimal, the result of expression will be integer. There has to be at least one of them decimal in expression to be casted to decimal - `isnan(1.0/0)` or `isnan(1/0.0)`.

Also division by zero is undefined behavior(1/0). May be better to try `isnan(0/1.0)`

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes when you change one of them to decimal it will work. However, I just show this as an example to focus on the error. My problem is I cannot compile GNSS-R software because the input cannot be changed. This is what I mean:in compiling GNSS-R I faced this error:"error: non-floating-point argument in call to function ‘__builtin_isnan’
 ddm_checkNAN(void)       { for(int i = 0; i<ddm.numBins; i++) { if( isnan((DDM[i])) ) return 1; } return 0; } ".

To avoid that I changed isnan((DDM[i])) to isnan((floor(DDM[i]))) and successfully compile the code,
Is this right?!

Comment: @ArminRahimi you can just use in "C" cast style `float(DDM[i])` to cast to float or `static_cast<float>(DDM[i])` in "C++" style. So your call function can look like `isnan(float(DDM[i]));` .